# illegal instruction after google-Assistant-demo

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have installed the google assistant on a raspberry pi 1b (one of the first revisions) without any issues following https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/python/run-sample when running the google-assistant-demo it returns and illegal instruction before exiting.

any advice on how to get this running?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Assistant Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/library/python/) that is part of the Google Assistant SDK only [supports](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview#features) x86_64 and ARMv7 (Raspberry Pi 2 and 3) architectures but not the ARMv6 (Raspberry Pi 1) architecture.